# Changing Dynamic Cascading Prompts with Crystal Reports 2008 and BO EDGE

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

We are using Crystal Reports and SAP BusinessObjects EDGE server for reporting.

At the moment there seems to be about 200 Dynamic Cascading Prompts on the Repository. I found info on how to edit these with Business View Manager but apparently it isn't included in the EDGE-version of BusinessObjects server.

Is there any way to edit these prompts from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was wrong about Business View Manager missing. Followed the advice from [this thread](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1583551) and found it in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\CrystalBVM.exe`